# Using angular-datatables DTOptions In Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am using [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) in a project. I am using it like this:

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First</th>
      <th>Last</th>
      <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
      <td>{{person.Id}}</td>
      <td>{{person.FirstName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.LastName}}</td>
      <td>{{person.Job}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Oddly enough, the table renders. However, it does not behave like a data table. Sorting is not loaded. Is there a way for me to check to see if `datatables` has been loaded? In my page, I have the following:

```
<link href="/libs/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/libs/angular-datatables/dist/datatables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>

angular.bootstrap($('#myApp'), ['myApp']);
```

MyApp is manually bootstrapped because there are multiple apps on the page. `app.js` has the following:

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'datatables', 'app.components']);

myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 
function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
  console.log(DTOptionsBuilder);
}])
;
```

the console.log statement prints `undefined`. This implies to me that `datatables` isn't being loaded. However, I'm not sure how to confirm that. I do not see any 404s in my console window. So, I assume that I'm at least downloading the necessary libraries. It feels like I'm not injecting `datatables` properly. However, it looks correct to me. Yet, sorting is not working and `DTOptionsBuilder` is printing undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

`Inline Array Annotation` is not provided properly
the correct way to do it is:

```js
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder',
function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {
  console.log(DTOptionsBuilder);
}])
;
```